# Mix web api action and non api action same controller asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

How to make one controller with web API and non web API actions on the same controller.

When I make this, I have a 404 error for the non web API action.

I have read in differents article that it's possible to mix with ASP.NET core , but does not work.

Return 404 for:

- http://localhost:5000/board/index/1
- http://localhost:5000/board/index?boardID=1

  ```
  [Route("api/[controller]")]
  public class BoardController : Controller
  {
      private IDataContext dataContext;

      public BoardController(IDataContext dataContext)
      {
          this.dataContext = dataContext;
      }


      public IActionResult Index(int boardID)
      {
          return View();
      }

      [HttpGet]
      public IEnumerable<Board> GetAll()
      {
      }
  }
  ```

**Or**

Return 404 for http://localhost:5000/api/board/

```
public class BoardController : Controller
{
    private IDataContext dataContext;

    public BoardController(IDataContext dataContext)
    {
        this.dataContext = dataContext;
    }

    public IActionResult Index(int boardID)
    {       
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Board> GetAll()
    {

    }
}
```

I think I get my second solution and use http://localhost:5000/board/getall for API action

Comment: you should split it, since your `GetAll` is a web-api-method and `Index` is a action of the controller. `GetAll` should be in a class like BoardRepository or BoardService. They both are completely different methods. You could call `GetAll` possibly from another controller with e.g. different DependencyInjection.. simply, don't merge those two (and it's neither beautiful). You could call many different Services/WebApi-methods on many controllers. This just makes it difficult.

Comment: Thanks, ok, otherwise I remove [Route("api/[controller]")] and that's work but it will not be a web api controller with particular route (POST, GET etc...) So I can split if I want standard REST

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class BoardController : Controller
{
    private IDataContext dataContext;

    public BoardController(IDataContext dataContext)
    {
        this.dataContext = dataContext;
    }

    [Route("/[controller]/[action]")]
    public IActionResult Index(int boardID)
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Board> GetAll()
    {
    }
}
```

Putting a slash in front of the route overrides the controller-level route attribute.